# How tu put id on html table td filled with json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have created this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rrzZU/263/.
What I would like to do is to change the colour of UID cases

```
'</td><td>' + json2[i].UID + '</td></tr>';
```

according to it's value. I know that I can do it easily by putting an id to each cases of UID column. So my question is how can I give a unique id to each cases of this column knowing that it's filled dynamically in a loop ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does giving an ID have to do with changing the color?

Comment: And your title mentions putting a listener on the table. How is that related?

Comment: add a class to the cells based on whatever values would make the change. Would help to know what expected results are

Comment: yes sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each UID to have a unique ID, could you use something like

```
'</td><td id="uid_'+i+'">' + json2[i].UID + '</td></tr>';
```

Which would output something like

```
'<td> id="uid_0">...
'<td id="uid_1">...
```

Comment: so if I do document.getElementById(uid_0).addEventListener("click....), will it work ?